# how to get extensive certificate info - in text form via cli?

Tags: command-line, certificate, x509

How do I get extensive info on an x509 certificate in text form so I can pipe its output further into scripts?

Plain openssl cmd for showing cert info is quite skimpy and non-descriptive (unless there is some fancy openssl cmd that I haven't come across yet?)

Ideal amount of info seems what e.g. Thunderbird provides under : Edit / Preferences / Privacy & security / Manage certificates / Your certificates / [select certificate from list ] / [click View ] => you see three tabs of extensive output of the certificate chain (in three tabs)

Answer (score 0):

`openssl x509 -text` really shows everything that's in the certificate.

```
openssl x509 -text < cert.pem
```

However, it only accepts one certificate per file. To see multiple at once, you need to either split them manually, or use `certtool -i` from GnuTLS – it has nearly the same output besides that:

```
certtool -i < fullchain.pem
```

Firefox and Thunderbird use NSS and store their certificates in a database. You can examine the contents using `certutil -L`, which again has very similar output:

```
# List names
certutil -L -d ~/.thunderbird/g5br1xzg.default

# Examine one certificate
certutil -L -d ~/.thunderbird/g5br1xzg.default -n "GTS CA 1O1"
```